# Insert x-value to polyfit vector to get y-value (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I used the Matlab command `polyfit` to interpolate a curve. I then wanted to calculate the y-max value of that curve. I have found the roots for the polynomial, so i now have an x-value I want to insert in the polynomial from `polyfit` to get the y-value for that x-value.

I have difficulties to get it working properly.

P is the polynomial, so as you know, P(1)^4, P(2)^3... and so on

```
P = [-1.99405270507682e+26  5.55362828633395e+24    -5.80027044841956e+22   2.69238494640005e+20    -4.68659390860982e+17]
```

The x-value I want to insert to get a y-value is

`x = 7.765633479578490e-04`

The y-value should be about 17.7.
Am I thinking right here? The x-value is correct, I have compared it to my plot.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in your calculations. With the values you give in your question, `P(x)` is enormous due to the enormous polynomial coefficients you have:

```
P =

  -1.9941e+026  5.5536e+024  -5.8003e+022  2.6924e+020  -4.6866e+017

>> x = 7.765633479578490e-04
x =   7.7656e-004
>> y = polyval(P,x)
y =  -2.9203e+017
```

These are the roots of your polynomial, they have very small imaginary parts, but given the enormous coefficients of the polynomial, they cannot be neglected:

```
>> format long g
>> roots(P)

ans =

        0.00696463336211033 +  9.88579484856405e-07i
        0.00696463336211033 -  9.88579484856405e-07i
        0.00696084682252702 +  1.06977927834625e-06i
        0.00696084682252702 -  1.06977927834625e-06i
```

Comment: Yeah, I also thought that. But that seems weird since the x-value after taking roots over the polynomial is correct. Also tried to use polyval. But I get y = 845.49...

Comment: The roots of the polynomial are all complex numbers, so not sure what you're on about.

Comment: Not to be rude, but no they are not, so not sure what you're on about.